# Does God pay attention? That is, does it make sense to talk about him paying attention to something?

Tags: theology

I'd like to know about different theological theories of what it might mean for God to pay attention to something. Thanks.

Comment: "*God, in this sense, may be understood to be, among many other things, pure conscious energy, so conscious that it loves and forgives and judges in one instantaneous, infinite act. Everywhere through the endless space of the universe there exists, shall we say, this Divine Attention which everything obeys without question.*" [Needleman, What is God?](https://rssb.org/2016-09-12.html)

Comment: According to Spinoza's God which has the perfect attribute of thought and a perfect thought must have its focused intentionality, thus his God by definition pays attention to all perfect thoughts, some of which perhaps transcend our cognitive limitations...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thanks. I suppose I'm interested in the idea that attention seems inherently selective (it doesn't seem to make sense to think that you can pay attention to something without ignoring other things). While the Spinoza idea is interesting, it doesn't seem to really engage with the question of what it would mean for God to pay attention to something, given the exclusionary nature of attention.

Comment: If the God is monotheistic, omniscient and omnipresent, then the human idea of exclusionary attention would not apply and the term can be used, as usual, only metaphorically. However, a distinction is made between general and particular providence, the latter signifying special interventions that guide/help individuals, answer prayers, etc., as opposed to general stewardship of the creation, which we would normally associate with "paying attention", see e.g. [Abraham, Particular Providence and Divine Actions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/oso/9780198786535.003.0005).

Comment: Spinoza's God has infinite attributes and cause-free which can certainly engage any different things to explain their causality. Indeed for our human mind it's normally impossible to focus on 2 different subjects at the same time thus you formed your "exclusionary nature of attention" claim. However, say you've fully mastered arithmetic calculation, then when you pay attention to 3+2=5, will you say you're *ignoring* 2+3=5 and 3+3=6? In the same metaphoric way God fully masters the whole web of perfect true thoughts and when you're paying attention to 3+2=5 it's really through God's thought...

Comment: so your clearly perceived attention is just a mode of God's attention, in fact per Spinoza almost all attributes we perceive and conceive are only *modes* (approximations) of God's true attributes which philosophers call *empirical* or *impure*. This actually reminds me many students complain they did something wrong during exam or homework because of not paying attention, I was always perplexed and would complain in return that if one's fully mastered the subject like arithmetic calculation, even in a raucous party could still get it right (paying attention sounds like a common easy excuse)..

Comment: If the question is about any god, it should say "gods", not "God". If this is about a specific cult, like Christianity, there are other sites here where members of those cults like christians can discuss their gods.

Comment: @Conifold Do you know of any theories in which that metaphor is clarified? In what sense is the thing that God does similar to what we would call paying attention.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has used the phrase "worshipworthy god", so I'll do it now

Comment: Abraham's is as good as any. We think of attention as shining a spotlight on something and then acting on it, but that is a derivative of our limited resources. There is no need for unlimited being to spotlight anything when everything is already brightly lit, but it can act in relation to localized circumstances in a way that would require *us* to spotlight them. To those within the circumstances it will have the effect of *receiving* attention. So it is being paid, but in an understandably non-exclusionary way.